# JQuery drag and drop - how to get at element being dragged?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

i am using jQuery UI - drag an drop

my html is :

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#example-1-2 .sortable-list").sortable({ connectWith: '#example-1-2 .sortable-list', opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move' });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example-1-2">
                <div id="Div2" class="column left first">
                    <ul id="leftlist" class="sortable-list">
                        <li class="sortable-item">Item1</li>
                        <li class="sortable-item">Item2</li>
                        <li class="sortable-item">Item3</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="column left">
                    <ul id="rightlist" class="sortable-list">
                        <li class="sortable-item">Item4</li>
                        <li class="sortable-item">Item5</li>
                        <li class="sortable-item">Item6</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So let's see if i pick `"item5"` from `rightlist` to and drop at `leftlist`

i want to get item5 in my $jquery Ajax method

How do i get this ?

what i tried is :

but using this [var order = $(this).sortable("toArray");] i got all elements , but i want one element who is being dragged

```
$("#leftlist,#rightlist").sortable({
                update: function (event, ui) {
                    var order = $(this).sortable("toArray");
                    $.ajax(
                     {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "WebForm3.aspx/LeftSideData",
                        data: "{'newdata': '" + order + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                     });
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Alan - Try looking at:

```
ui.item
```

Per the jQueryUI Sortable API documentation, 'item': "The jQuery object representing the current dragged element"

Are you sure you don't want to also be using "Draggable", since you're dragging and dropping from one list to another?  You can use Draggable's connectToSortable to as the API doc states: "Allows the draggable to be dropped onto the specified sortables."

via API documentation:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ connectToSortable: "#my-sortable" });
```